# Send function of ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js

Do you know what this line does and how it works?:

`ethers.provider.send("evm_setNextBlockTimestamp", [1637102259]);`

I have not found good documentation about it on internet.

Thank you

Take care
Pierre

Answer (score 1):

The `send` method sends a raw JSON RPC call, where the first parameter is the RPC method and the second parameter is an array of arguments specific to the method.

In your example it is calling a RPC method named `evm_setNextBlockTimestamp` and the parameter is a single timestamp. I assume the node you are talking to here has that method implemented (it is not an official one), and that it would set `block.timestamp` for the next block to `1637102259`.

You can read more about the `send` method [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/#JsonRpcProvider-send).

You can read more on the official JSON RPC methods [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/).